# How to get transaction id?

Tags: stripe-payments

I need to store a transaction id after a successful transaction.
I have a web server which handles webhooks from stripe but I can't find the transaction id.
If it is not in the webhooks how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what traction id you refer to, and what webhook event name you are looking at. There is no "transaction id" in Stripe. They only have, for example, Payment Intent Id (pi_xxx) or Checkout Session Id (cs_text_xxx)

Comment: According to stripe documentation you can get a transaction object if you have the transaction id https://stripe.com/docs/api/issuing/transactions

Comment: As the documentation URL you shared shows, that is **SPECIFIC** to "Issuing" - issuing cards (with available debit balances).  It is NOT AT ALL general to Stripe.

Comment: Yes true, it's Issuing and not general Stripe